# Ajax div click event

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, facebook-like

This is a two-step code. The user should click like and then the click continue to proceed. However, i can;t get the div event to work. The like button is in-between a div called postos. If something is clicked between this div it should make thanks.php accessible.

also tried this

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">  


$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#postos").click(function () {
    $("#linkos").attr('href', 'thanks.php');
  });
});


 </script>  

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script> 



        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

        <div class="fb-like">

<div id="postos">
<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" url="http://tehcplz.org" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
</div>


<br><br>

<p>Continue <a id="linkos" href='javascript:window.alert("like us");'> <br/>Click to continue </a>
<br>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#postos > *").click(function () {
    $("#linkos").attr('href', 'thanks.php');
  });
});
```